# gradle idea plugin: libraries marked as "unresolved dependencies"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When trying to run the idea plugin for my gradle project, a number of my intellij libraries are in error with `Library: 'gradle: unresolved_dependency_blah_blah' has broken classes path`. the library itself is marked as "unresolved dependencies"

My gradle project is a multi module, I have applied the idea plugin to `allprojects`.

> Intellij version is #IU-134.1007
>
> gradle version is 1.11

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** these are an example of some of the dependencies i have:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'


dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:3.2.0.201312181205-r'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'org.junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

all three have the errors

Comment: You'd have to provide more details, such as which exact dependencies can't be resolved. It could mean that you didn't declare any repositories, misspelled the dependencies, the dependencies don't exist, etc. `gradle build` would likely fail in such a case.

Comment: I have adjusted the question with my failing examples

Comment: And what if you use gradle from the command line? Does it succeed then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved...

The issue was that i had not declared any repositories. (thank you peter)

adding the following to my root project resolved the dependencies correctly:

```
allprojects {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}
```